# How to detect DoubleClickEvent on DataTable Column name?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, click, double-click

I have a **DataGridView CellClick Event** and a separate **DoubleClick Event** for the SearchByState form in the image below.

If the user clicks into a cell and presses the **OK button** then the ID would be transferred back to the main form.
If the user **DoubleClicks** in a cell then that would **"btnOk.PerformClick()"** and return the data to the main form.

I want to know how I can detect if the column name is clicked so that when the **OK button** is clicked that nothing happens because the column name was clicked.

```
Private Sub CustomersDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, _
     e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles CustomersDataGridView.CellDoubleClick

    btnOk.Enabled = True
    Me.Tag = Me.CustomerDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0)Value
    Me.btnOk.PerformClick()
End Sub
```

I'm thinking of using an **IF Statement** to declare that if Me.Tag = "" or Nothing that the PerformClick does not execute. Any Ideas?

[image: My Datatable]

Comment: There is a separate `ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick` event. I doubt that the `CellDoubleClick` event fires if you click the column header. The EventArgs `e` also has `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` properties showing you where the user has clicked.

Comment: Believe me, it used to dump when I clicked the ColumnHeader until I re-wrote it. Now when I click it, it closes and returns nothing. Is there a way to use the ColunmnHeaderMouseDoubleClick to prevent anything from happening aside from the table be organized by the column ASC or DESC?

Comment: You've already been told what to do: use the RowIndex of the event args to determine whether it's a column header that was clicked and do nothing if it is.